# Binding to Service from a BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: android, service, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to start a `Service` I have created called **`MyService`** from a `BroadcastReceiver`. My `BroadcastReceiver` is a inner class of a `Fragment`. So my code looks like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    /*
     * Lots of code taken out
     */

    private class ServiceListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

        private Context parentContext = null;

        public ServiceListener(Context parentContext){
            this.parentContext = parentContext;
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.serverListener");
            this.parentContext.registerReceiver(this, intentFilter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(arg0, MyService.class);
            MyFragment.this.getActivity().startService(i);
            MyFragment.this.getActivity().bindService(i, mConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            //code taken out
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            //more code taken out
        }
    };

}
```

I can see the call going into the `onReceive()` method in `ServiceListener`, but after it finishes going over the lines to start and bind the `service`, I never hit breakpoints on the `onBind()` method inside `MyService`, or on my `onServiceConnected()` either.

Does anyone have an idea for what could be wrong?

Ps. As a side note, the `Broadcast` is coming from the `FragmentActivity` which holds a `TabHost`. The `TabHost` is what creates the `Fragment`s, ie. **MyFragment**. If there is an easier way to call down into a `Fragment` from an `FragmentActivity` to trigger the `Service` to start and bind, I am all ears!

Thanks!

**Edit:**

**I didn't have my `service` defined in my `Manifest.xml`... It's all working now!** `</silly>`

Comment: Can you please provide the solution as a proper answer and accept it after 8 hours. Don't forget to include the relevant part from the manifest.

Comment: Please remember that it is now standard practice to post an answer as an answer, not as part of the question.